# c++ toupper() to compare two strings

Tags: c++, string, toupper

I have created a set of algorithms that takes an input of a string vector, checks whether any of the strings occur more than once: if so erases all additional occurrences of the string from the vector, then outputs the new, 'lighter' array without the redundancies.

It works great except now I am to make it case-insensitive; I am attempting to simply add the `toupper()` std function to the `==` comparison statement, however it does not seem to work.

I have a more familiar background with Java and am trying to learn C++.
Can someone please show me how to correct my syntax?

```
// Output old list.
cout << endl << "==========\nOld list:\n==========";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << endl << list[i];
}
cout << endl << endl;

// Check uniqueness.
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    for (int j = i+1; j < count; j++) {
        if (toupper(list[i]) == toupper(list[j])) {
            list[j] = "";
            count--;
        }
    }

// Output new list.
cout << endl << "==========\nNew list:\n==========";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << endl << list[i];
}
cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::string>` with `std::remove_if` and a `lambda`?

Comment: @OMGtechy Is that case insensitive?

Comment: @Jim22150 Does the order of the strings in the list needs to be maintained ?

Comment: @Mahesh, yes output same order, I'd like to keep my algorithms the same. This is not what the question is about (to OMGtechy & Scott).

Comment: how is it not working? what is list? std::string[N]?

Comment: Yes, it is a string array, not a character array.

Comment: @Jim22150 it's whatever you want it to be, the lambda would define whether you wanted it to be case sensitive or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop leaves *"holes"* in the `list` <strike>array</strike> vector, but the size of the <strike>array</strike> vector does not change (but you decrease your upper bound `count`)

<strike>There are probably many other alternatives, but if you don't want to modify it much, probably you need in an addtional loop to copy *non-empty* elements from the `list` array into a new array</strike>

### Edit: integrating some of the answers

First we're going to have a function to do the toUpper (this is modified from @Jim22150)

```
std::string stringToUpper(const std::string &input) {
    std::string toBeModified=input;
    std::transform(toBeModified.begin(), toBeModified.end(), toBeModified.begin(), ::toupper);
    return toBeModified;
}
```

Now, we must not leave holes, so we should use erase (as @Scott Christopher Stauffe indicated):

```
// Output old list.
cout << endl << "==========\nOld list:\n==========";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << endl << list[i];
}
cout << endl << endl;

// Check uniqueness.
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
        if(stringToUpper(list[i]) == stringToUpper(list[j])) {
            list.erase(j,1);
            count--;
        }
    }
}

// Output new list.
cout << endl << "==========\nNew list:\n==========";
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    cout << endl << newlist[i];
}
cout << endl << endl;
```

Comment: Yes, it would be nice to avoid this. I am trying to implement Scott's suggestion but it looks like I may need another for loop which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Comment: @Jim22150 ... yes but real the problem is that you cannot shrink an array, unless you copy it. If you can use a vector instead on an array, that would allow you to erase from it...

Comment: list[] **is** a vector, not an array.

Comment: @Jim22150 ok... this was very confusing. I've edited my answer above to integrate some of the ideas floating around. I really haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

I just did a quick google of toupper and I didn't find any string versions of it. The only standard touppper() I have seen is `int toupper(int c);` - that means you can only use it to compare individual characters! Have you tried [stricmp()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k59z8dwe.aspx)?

```
        if ( 0 == _stricmp(list[i], list[j]) ) {
            list[j] = "";
            count--;
        }
```

Depending on your compiler you may or may not have this function at your disposal.

Comment: I am using VS'13 so this function would be ideal, however it seems to only be used for individual characters, not entire strings. So I could use it but I'd have to make another `for` loop, inside of the conditional, correct?

Comment: @Jim22150, `stricmp()` will accept two strings as parameters so no need for another loop. If you want to continue using `toupper()` then you need a loop to compare individual chars.

Answer (score 1):

@DaveS, thanks Dave I will try that; it looks clean and short. However, I found dirtier solution using transform and making a duplicate of the old vector.

```
    // Output old list.
    cout << endl << "==========\nOld list:\n==========";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << endl << list[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;

    // Check uniqueness.
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++) {
            std::transform(list[i].begin(), list[i].end(), list[i].begin(), ::toupper);
            std::transform(list[j].begin(), list[j].end(), list[j].begin(), ::toupper);
            if (list[i] == list[j]) {
                newlist[j] = "";
                count--;
            }
        }

    // Output new list.
    cout << endl << "==========\nNew list:\n==========";
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << endl << newlist[i];
    }
    cout << endl << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle C++ strings as easily as Java strings, then the [Boost String Algorithms Library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/string_algo.html) is the way to go. Installing Boost may be a bit hard for a newbie C++ programmer (although it's a breeze compared to many other C++ libraries), but it pays off.

Your problem will essentially be reduced to this:

```
boost::algorithm::to_upper_copy(list[i]) == boost::algorithm::to_upper_copy(list[j])
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
list[j] = ""; // should never work.
```

You can remove a char by using erase.

```
list.erase(j, 1);
```

Alternatively, to avoid this altogether, you could use a temporary "builder" string and just push_back chars to it when needed.

Comment: .erase() seems to be only for characters in vectors, however I need to erases string elements of a vector. Any clues, preferably without additional loops?

Comment: It was mentioned it was an array, not a vector

Comment: @jsantander yes sorry, I adjusted my question; vector, not array.